# Manga where the MC has some sort of system that helps him develop by annoying people

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't remember many details, but I believe the original language was Chinese. The protagonist is an orphan and has a sister to take care of.

Before he got the system's power, he used to sell tofu or whatnot on the streets. The system is designed to give points to him when he annoys or makes fun of other people, much similar to the system from "Strongest Anti M.E.T.A". The difference is that he stays in his original world.

Also, I think the art style was similar to "The Lord of Catastrophe".

Comment: What sort of world/time period was the story set in? And did the main character have short hair or long hair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Da Wang Rao Ming* (*Spare Me, Great Lord!*, 2021).

From [this review on MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/reviews.php?id=435089):

> **Lu Shu, an orphan abandoned by his Mother grew up in poverty with an adopted little sister Lu Xiaoyu struggling to gather money for their tuition**. However, it all changes when Lu Shu is hit by a truck and dies in an accident. Activating powers passed on from his Mother, **Lu Shu is revived and gets granted a Gacha System where he earns points from angering or intimidating people.** The points he gathers are used to spin the wheel in hopes of getting a special cultivation fruit, single use healing, body upgrades and more.
>
> [...]
>
> At times the smaller details were very hard to avoid such as **counting anger points** which was done much better in "I annoy millions of cultivators" because at the end of each episode Lu Shu would be in a surplus of unspent points and arbitrarily spend them when needed. **In the beginning we see that most of his points go to failed gacha spins and stinky tofu** with special attributes but apart from that we rarely see the gacha system utilized especially later in the series.

---

Found by sheer, dumb luck: my partner described it to me briefly earlier this week when I asked him what he was watching. I prompted him to give me the show's name just as he was headed to bed tonight, he could not remember, but fortunately his browser history did!

Comment: +1 for checking partner's browser history and still being able to write an answer. /s

Comment: @Chris he's the one who checked his history, not me :p